# ADBannerView Unhandled error shown in the console

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed the apple developing guide documentation for adding an iAd on my iOS app programmatically.though I searched among the previous solutions on stackoverflow but unluckily none of them seems to be helping me.here is the following error:

> iAdBanner failed [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0xb07b9a0 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}. One thing worth mentioning that most of the time I get the message that iAdBanner loaded. here is the following code of my project SinglePlayerViewController.h

And Code is as below

```
 #import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface SinglePlayerViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

    {
    ADBannerView *adView;
    }
```

SinglePlaerViewController.m code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
        adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
        adView.frame = adFrame;
        adView.delegate =self;
        [self.view addSubview:adView];
    }
-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"iAdBanner failed");
}
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{

    NSLog(@"iAdBanner loaded"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following:

```
@interface SinglePlayerViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) ADBannerView *adView;

@end
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    CGRect adFrame = self.adView.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-self.adView.frame.size.height;
    self.adView.frame = adFrame;
    self.adView.delegate =self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.adView];
}
```

HTH

Comment: currentContentSizeIdentifier was Deprecated since iOS 6

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't go along with his problem.